# How to crop image from image src in a specific size

Tags: images

I got the image src from user input by a metabox field. Now I want to render this image in a specific size. Just as like WordPress image cropping in a specific size.

I tried to get the image ID from the src then used the bellow function to get the image src with a sized image.

```
<?php
$img_id = get_image_id($img_src);
$sized_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'image_size');
```

And here is the `get_image_id()` function:

```
function get_image_id($image_url) {
global $wpdb;
$attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url ));
return $attachment[0];
}
```

Actually, I'm not getting the image IDs for uploaded images with this function. Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `attachment_url_to_postid()` to get the post id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has a function solely designed for this purpose. the `attachment_url_to_postid()` allows you to retrieve an attachment's ID from it's URL, which then you can use to get the post's ID later.

If you want to do it by writing a MySQL query, i would however prefer to suggest searching the file's name in `meta_value` instead:

```
$basename = basename ($image_url);
$sql = "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_value = '$basename '";
$id = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

GUID columns are hardcoded in database once you publish a post. So, if you publish a post on localhost, a sample GUID will be like this:

```
http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/my-image.jpg
```

But you will be searching for an *online* URL of your image by using this:

```
$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url ));
```

Which will return nothing, obviously. However you can use `LIKE` in conjunction with basename:

```
$img_name = basename ($image_url);
$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid LIKE '%s';", $img_name ));
```

Which is kind of the same as the first approach.